# What is the limit of $\sum _{k=0}^n\:\frac{\exp\left(-k\right)}{2^k}$ when $n->\infty $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I just wanna know what is the limit of this serie above.
I proved that this serie is convergent using Cauchy's convergence test, and this serie is increasing, and $\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\:Un<=2$
So the limit must be 2. 
Am I right ?

Comment: $V_n=1-1/n$ is also an increasing sequence bounded by $2$. But $V_n$ doesn't converge to $2$.

Comment: You can only be sure that the result is smaller than 2.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yep you're right ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with ratio $\frac 1 {2e}$.  As $n\to \infty$, it converges to $\frac 1{1-\frac {1}{2e}}$, or around 1.2253996735605641.

Answer (score 2):

$$
2^k = \mathrm{e}^{k\ln 2}
$$
so you are computing the sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\mathrm{e}^{-k-k\ln 2}=\sum_{k=0}^n\mathrm{e}^{-(1+\ln 2)k}
$$
or
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\mathrm{e}^{-(1+\ln 2)}\right]^k
$$
which we can state as $a^k$ thus we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n a^k 
$$
this is a geometric sum so as long as 
$$
a = \mathrm{e}^{-(1+\ln 2)} < 1
$$
we can converge.